# Filtering documents by length of an array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following schema:

```
const RecipeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    ingredients: [
        {
            name: {
                type: String,
                required: true,
                trim: true
            },
            amount: {
                type: Number,
                required: true
            }
        }
    ]
});

const Recipe = mongoose.model('Recipe',RecipeSchema);
export {Recipe as default}
```

I am stuck on filtering the recipes by providing two numbers: min and max, and return the list of recipes that have the number of ingredients ( length of ingredients array ) greater than min and less than max.
Can you help me on this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sequence finally did it:

```
{$where: "this.ingredients.length >= " + min + " && this.ingredients.length <= " + max}
```

Answer (score 0):

> here I have used the $expr operator to filter out all those documents
> which have sizes greater than or equal to min and less than or equal
> to max.

```
   let min = 1
   let max  = 2

RecipeModel.find({"$expr":{$gte:[{$size:"$ingredients"},min], $lte:[{$size:"$ingredients"},max]}})
```

Comment: That's great, but i need to compare with the number of ingredients in the array, not the amount

Comment: what do you mean by number?

Comment: the zie of the array

Comment: for that, you can create an extra field in your schema and like `ingredientsSize` and then you can compare with that field

Comment: Thank you, but i would like to find a solution that does not need this step

Comment: I have updated my answer check if it working for you

Comment: No, it does not work, but i foun a solution: {$where: "this.ingredients.length >= " + min + " && this.ingredients.length <= " + max}